# Detect window width and change jQuery UI tooltip position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, tooltip

I have been trying to change the jQuery UI tooltip position based on screen width, but I can't get it to work. **[[fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/stonecold111/XFKN2/2/)** Would anyone please show me how to detect the width of the browser and change the tooltip position accordingly?

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({

      var wi = $(window).width();   

        if (wi <= 800){

        position: {
        my: "left+190 top",
        at: "center top"
    },
                        } else {                       
        position: {
        my: "left+20 top",
        at: "center top"  }, }       


        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        },
        show: null, 
        close: function (event, ui) {
            ui.tooltip.hover(

            function () {
                $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
            },

            function () {
                $(this).fadeOut("300", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                })
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid code:

```
$(document).tooltip({

      var wi = $(window).width();   

        if (wi <= 800){

        position: {
        my: "left+190 top",
        at: "center top"
    },
       }
        else {
```

The `tooltip` plugin accepts an options `object`, it is not a function body to write arbitrary code within. Move your conditional window size logic outside of the tooltip:

http://jsfiddle.net/XFKN2/3/